# UITableViewAutomaticDimension along with heightForRow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, size

I need to use UITableViewAutomaticDimension for some cells and also need to use heightForRow for some other cells

Is it possible to use them both within a same table view?
If possible how do I do it?

Comment: it is possible but why you are trying to supply constant height for cells if your AutoLayOut constraints are correct you can achieve this with out adding this.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can do it as below

In `viewDidLoad` method

```
self.tblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 180
```

In `heightForRowAt indexPath` method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //Condition for specific height
    if indexPath.row != 1 {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    else {
        return 150
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()         
        //Add this code
        //Requests that UITableView use the default value for a given dimension.
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 // estimate Row Height
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

      }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 0{
            if indexPath.row == 0{
                return 44 // add your fix row height
            }else{
                return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            }
        }
        return 0

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4.0

In `viewWillAppear` method

```
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

In `heightForRowAt indexPath` method

```
 if (tableView == tableView) {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
 } else {

   return 150

 }
```